# MySQL - Multirow Sum without Subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery

I currently have this working using a Sub-query, but as the DB grows this will become HUGELY inefficient. I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to do what I need to do without sub-queries?

I need to have my final output look like so:

```
Question, Answer, Responses, Charts included in Response Count
Did this work?, N/A, 26, 30
Did this work?, Yes, 4, 30
```

This is my current query:

```
SELECT
  bq_text,
  ba_a,
  bq_id,
  COUNT(ba_a)   AS ba_aC,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM board_done_sheet WHERE sd_b_id = bs.bs_id AND sd_sub = 1) AS sd_chartnumC
FROM board_done_sheet AS sh
  LEFT JOIN board_done bd
    ON (bd.bd_id = sh.sd_bd_id)
  LEFT JOIN boardsubs bs
    ON (bd.bd_b_id = bs.bs_id)
  LEFT JOIN b_q_answers ba
    ON (sh.sd_s_id = ba.ba_s_id)
  LEFT JOIN bsquestions bq
    ON (bq.bq_id = ba.ba_q_id)
  LEFT JOIN multiples m
    ON (ba.ba_m_id = m.m_id)
  LEFT JOIN users u
    ON (u.us_id = bd.bd_d_id)
  LEFT JOIN profiles p
    ON (p.p_u_id = bd.bd_d_id)
  LEFT JOIN users rev
    ON (rev.us_id = bd.bd_rev)
WHERE sd_sub = '1' AND bq_text <> 'Date' AND bq_id = 380
GROUP BY bs_id, bq_text, ba_a
```

That works perfectly, the problem is it has to use sub-queries which as time goes by will get less efficient.

I'm just wondering if there is a better more efficient way to do that summed field without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably the subquery you're concerned about is the one in your toplevel `SELECT`.

That is easy to refactor so it won't get repeated.

Just JOIN it to the rest of the table. You'll want this sort of thing:

```
SELECT
 bq_text, ...
 COUNT(ba_a)   AS ba_aC,
 countup.countup AS sd_chartnumC
FROM board_done_sheet AS sh
LEFT JOIN board_done bd
           ON (bd.bd_id = sh.sd_bd_id)
...
LEFT JOIN users rev
          ON (rev.us_id = bd.bd_rev)
JOIN (
          SELECT COUNT(*) AS countup , sd_b_id
            FROM board_done_sheet 
           WHERE sd_sub = 1
        GROUP BY sd_b_id
     ) AS countup ON countup.sd_b_id = bs.bs_id
WHERE sd_sub = '1' 
  AND bq_text <> 'Date' 
  AND bq_id = 380
GROUP BY bs_id, bq_text, ba_a
```

The `countup` subquery generates a summary table of counts and ids, and then joins it to the other tables.

A JOIN cascade of this complexity may become inefficient for other reasons as your table grows if you don't structure your indexes correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try now. Luckily I have indexes on all the columns used to join, etc. So that should keep it relatively lively :)

Comment: I'm receiving this error: `Unknown column 'bs.bs_id' in 'where clause'`

Comment: I misunderstood the purpose of the SELECT COUNT(*) clause; see the reworked subquery.  I don't have your data, of course, so I can't debug these queries.

Comment: Yep, it works now. This is pretty good as it is taking half the time to generate the results as my sub-query did. Thanks.